# AWS SQL Server. Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, amazon-rds

I have an on-premise SQL Server and SSIS 2014. I also have a SQL Server database (Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition (64-bit)) in AWS RDS. There is a simple package in on-premise SSIS than must get data from tables in AWS SQL Server and transfer it to an on-premise database. For connection to AWS I use SQL Server Native Client 11.0.

After successful transferring data from several tables, I get the exception

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection".

I tried different scenarios:

- loading per 8 tables simultaneously, then next 8 tables and etc.
- loading per 6 tables simultaneously, then next 6 tables and etc.
- loading per 2 tables simultaneously, then next 2 tables and etc.
- loading data with waitings

But every time I get an exception mentioned above.

For AWS SQL Server are applied the next settings:

[image]

Any ideas what the reason could be?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for the answer. Regarding rules creation. DB in AWS managed by DevOps team. Can these rules affect connection? As I mentioned in the question data from some tables are transferred successfully but then the exception appears. Regarding driver. On-premise SQL Server is a legacy system. All settings are tuned several years ago. Can the driver solve the problem?

Comment: My questions are no longer relevant after the edits.

Comment: If I'm reading the narrative correctly, you're able to successfully transfer tables but are getting this issue after a while? That is indeed strange. If you were getting no success, I'd chalk this up to a general connectivity issue (e.g. firewall, server not running, etc).

Comment: Guys thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is it was used the connection string to the listener. When the 'listener' was deleted from the connection string the data transfer became work fastly and without any issues.